# cfajax jquery javascript

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml

I'm using Jquery datepicker on a lot of text input fields.  It is not working. I have my javascrippt in an include file and do a savecontent so that I can use cfhtmlhead.  Dev tools console shows me an error;

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(initCandidateScript,null,false,true);
// Uncaught ReferenceError: initCandidateScript is not defined  <---------console error
/* ]]> */
</script>



<cfajaximport tags="cfgrid,cfform,cfinput-autosuggest,cfinput-  datefield,cftextarea,cfwindow">
<style>
#ui-datepicker-div { z-index:10000; } 
</style>
<cfsavecontent variable="JobAdScript">
<script language=JavaScript src="picker.js"></script> 
<script language=JavaScript src="JobAdsJavascript.js"></script> 
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#JobAdScript#" />
<cfset ajaxOnLoad("initCandidateScript")>
```

This code is in the include js file;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function initCandidateScript() {
        $(function () {
            alert('starting');
            $('input.datestuff').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `initCandidateScript` definition outside the document-ready event callback. There is no point in delaying a function *definition* until the DOM is ready.

Besides that, the CF JavaScript framework seems to delay the execution of that function until everything is ready and loaded anyway.

So, simply define the function like this in your .js file - without wrapping it with a DOM ready event.

```
function initCandidateScript() {
    $(function() {
        alert('starting');
        $('input.datestuff').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
        });
    });
}
```

Actually, you can simplify it even more since right now you have *another* DOM ready callback inside your function which you do not need:

```
function initCandidateScript() {
    $('input.datestuff').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    });
}
```

Comment: I did that and got the alert "startup" but no date function on the input fields.

Comment: does your `<input class="datestuff">` actually exist in the DOM?

Comment: function initCandidateScript() {
      $(function () {
      alert('starting');
      $('input.datestuff').datepicker({
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker'<-err
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
     });
   });
        }

Comment: This means jQuery UI is not loaded at all.

Comment: jquery 1.3.2   and jquery_ui.min  and jquery.min are loaded

Comment: why are you using such an ancient version? and if you indeed load jquery twice that's your problem. especially if you load another jquery version after loading jquery ui.

Comment: The actual lines are;
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I found about 7 included pages that had jquery 1.3.2 included. I have commented them out. But still not datepicker.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: initCandidateScript is not defined
But it is defined;
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
    function initCandidateScript() {
      $(function() {
 $('input.datestuff').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
 });
      });
    }

Comment: probably you try to call it before the file containing it is included

Comment: The only place it isn't working now is withing a cfwindow.  Even if I add the code to that window, it doesn't work (no date widget).